# Show posts by custom field in a separated sub-menu in WordPress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show some posts list in a separated sub-menu in WordPress dashboard that has a specific custom fields.

For example some of my posts has *edited_pending_done* **meta_key**.
how should I show them in a separated sub-menu?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Could you please show us what you've tried, show us some code etc.